# Generate and link static css files on Angular universal

Tags: css, angular, webpack, angular-universal

I am a newbie with Angular and probably my inexperience don't permits me to found a solution to my problem:

I have a basic setup with Angular 4 with Angular Universal an I use Foundation.

My issue is that all global styles generated using sass are imported inline in the html head like:

```
<style type="text/css">
@charset "UTF-8";
/**
 * Foundation for Sites by ZURB
 * Version 6.3.0
 * foundation.zurb.com
 * Licensed under MIT Open Source
 */
/**
 * Foundation for Sites by ZURB
 * Version 6.4.3
 * foundation.zurb.com
 * Licensed under MIT Open Source
 */
```

an so on...

a file called `styles.bundle.css` it's generated in the `./dist/server` directory but is not used and webpack still to generate the `bundle.styles.js` file in addiction to inline css file.

Some config files:

Webpack conf:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: { server: './server.ts' },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js'] },
  target: 'node',
  // this makes sure we include node_modules and other 3rd party libraries
  externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // Temporary Fix for issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
    // for "WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression"
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    )
  ]
}</pre>
```

Angular CLI conf:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "My project"
  },
  "apps": [{
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist/browser",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    {
      "platform": "server",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist/server",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.server.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.universal.loc.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [{
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: What if you don't include styles.scss on your server conf in angular cli?

Comment: Thanks @David,

define the styles like this is not enough?

    "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],

Comment: I meant, what if you have  "styles": [] pour the server conf

Comment: Sorry, I've read in a hurry..

without declare `styles.scss` in server conf, the static css file is not generated, buth nothing change occurs on generated html/js files